# How to redirect any non www subdomain to www

Tags: nginx, regex

I just can't figure out how to redirect any non-www subdomain to www.

When I go to a domain without the www subdomain i get redirected to `www./`. Like the $domain extension is not working.

```
server {
    listen          80 default_server;
    listen          [::]:80;
    listen          443 default_server;
    listen          [::]:443;
    server_name     ~^(?<sub>\.)?(?<domain>.+)$;

    if ($sub != 'www') {
        return      301 $scheme://www.$domain;
    }
}
```

Could anyone help me figure out how to get the correct configuration to do the following?

```
domain-a.com > www.domain-a.com
dev.domain-b.com > www.domain-b.com
www.domain-a.com > Gets to see the website.
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you mean that you want a redirect from `*.example.com` and `example.com` to `www.example.com`.

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80;
    listen 443 default_server;
    listen [::]:443;

    ssl_certificate /path/to/certificate;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/key;

    server_name ~ example\.com$;

    return 301 $scheme://www.example.com;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80;
    listen 443 default_server;
    listen [::]:443;

    ssl_certificate /path/to/certificate;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/key;

    server_name www.example.com;

    # Other directives for www.example.com
}
```

First server block matches any domain name that ends with `example.com`, and issues a redirect.

Second server block matches `www.example.com`. nginx processes first full `server_name` matches before matching wildcard / regular expression matches, as described in nginx [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html)

Even better would be to define a separate `default_server` block, which would return 404 status code for requests to any other domain names.